# Wow64GetThreadContext returning same values for WOW64_CONTEXT structure members

Tags: c++, c, debugging, winapi

I am compiling to 64-bit and calling the functions on a 32-bit(Wow64) processes thread. No errors are being returned for any functions.

But for some reason the CPU register members in the `WOW64_CONTEXT`struct passed to `Wow64GetThreadContext` are always the same values each and every time the function is called. Even though I initialize every member in the struct to 0, `WOW64_CONTEXT wow64ctxt = {0}`.

As far as I know I am doing everything correctly but I always get the same values for each member in `WOW64_CONTEXT`.

Here's my code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_IE_WIN8
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD dwPid      = 0;

    BOOL found       = FALSE;
    BOOL wow64       = FALSE;

    HANDLE hProcess  = NULL;
    HANDLE hThread   = NULL;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    THREADENTRY32 th32;

    WOW64_CONTEXT wow64ctxt = {0};

    printf("PID: ");
    scanf("%lu", &dwPid);

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPid);

    if(hProcess == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error getting handle to process: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if(!IsWow64Process(hProcess, &wow64))
    {
        printf("Error determining bitness of process: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if(!wow64)
    {
        printf("Error, not a 32-bit process... closing program\n");
        return 1;
    }

    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, dwPid);

    if(hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error getting thread snapshot: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    th32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    if(!Thread32First(hSnapshot, &th32))
    {
        printf("Error Thread32First: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    while(Thread32Next(hSnapshot, &th32))
    {
        if(th32.th32OwnerProcessID == dwPid)
        {
            found = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
    {
        printf("Thread could not be found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, th32.th32ThreadID);

    if(hThread == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error getting a handle to thread %lu: %lu\n", th32.th32ThreadID, GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if(Wow64SuspendThread(hThread) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error suspending thread: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    wow64ctxt.ContextFlags = WOW64_CONTEXT_FULL;

    if(!Wow64GetThreadContext(hThread, &wow64ctxt))
    {
        printf("Error getting thread context: %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }

    ResumeThread(hThread);

    printf("EAX: %lu\n", wow64ctxt.Eax);
    printf("EBP: %lu\n", wow64ctxt.Ebp);
    printf("EIP: %lu\n", wow64ctxt.Eip);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that the context values are wrong.

Comment: In most GUI programs, the main thread spends most of its time making the same operating system call, waiting for incoming messages.  It is likely that most or all of the registers will be the same unless by sheer luck you happen to catch the thread at a point when it is doing something more interesting.  Might that explain your observations?